# How can I adjust my code so that the only output is the final iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

When I run my code:

```
import math as ma

C = 10
n_ran = 5
f_t = 0.17
n_val = []

# Calculation
for n in range(n_ran):
    f_t = 0.17
    e_bit = 1- ma.e**(f_t*C)
    n_add = ((f_t*C)**n)/ma.factorial(n)
    n_val.append(n_add)
    print(n_val)
```

I receive every iteration plus every previous iteration, like so:

```
[1.0]
[1.0, 1.7000000000000002]
[1.0, 1.7000000000000002, 1.4450000000000003]
[1.0, 1.7000000000000002, 1.4450000000000003, 0.8188333333333335]
[1.0, 1.7000000000000002, 1.4450000000000003, 0.8188333333333335, 0.34800416666666684]
```

How could I change my code to get just a that final iteration as a list containing all 5 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unindent the `print()` call.

```
for n in range(n_ran):
    f_t = 0.17
    e_bit = 1- ma.e**(f_t*C)
    n_add = ((f_t*C)**n)/ma.factorial(n)
    n_val.append(n_add)

print(n_val)
```

I'd also recommend different formatting:

```
print(*n_val, sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
1.0
1.7000000000000002
1.4450000000000003
0.8188333333333335
0.34800416666666684
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing while *inside* the loop, so it's printing the `list` `n_val` upon every iteration.

You can move your `print` statement outside the loop

```
for n in range(n_ran):
    f_t = 0.17
    e_bit = 1- ma.e**(f_t*C)
    n_add = ((f_t*C)**n)/ma.factorial(n)
    n_val.append(n_add)

print(n_val)
```